# Is there a record number limit with django-import-export and if not is it removing what it thinks are duplicates?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have a csv that contains 2500 records. After import, it is down to 1100 records. Is DIE removing what it thinks are duplicates? If yes, how do I shut that off? If not, is there a recommended amount of records to import at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep one field unique for it.

In resource meta class just add `import_id_fields`.

Definition:

```
import_id_fields = [u'id']
    Controls which object fields will be used to identify existing instances.
```

Hopefully, it will work for you. :)

Comment: The issue was that I had a unique on the last name. So if I had two, then it wouldn't import them. So I added all the fields to the index fields and then it worked!